# Case statement causing RSV-SRV-0042 trace back error in cognos

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-10

I get this error because of the case statement included in the query item used for my year prompt use value. the prompt does what I want but combined with the month prompt which points directly to a table I get the error message.

here is the case statement 
case when ([Stat]=1) then ('Current Period') else ([Yr]) end

And the error I get is

```
RSReportService.cpp(747): RSQFCommandException: CCL_CAUGHT: RSReportService::processImpl()RSReportServiceMethod.cpp(258): RSQFCommandException: CCL_RETHROW: RSReportServiceMethod::process(): promptPagingForward_RequestRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(854): RSQFCommandException: RSASyncExecutionThread::checkExceptionRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(311): RSQFCommandException: CCL_CAUGHT: RSASyncExecutionThread::runImpl(): promptPagingForward_RequestRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(910): RSQFCommandException: CCL_RETHROW: RSASyncExecutionThread::processCommand(): promptPagingForward_RequestExecution/RSRenderExecution.cpp(585): RSQFCommandException: CCL_RETHROW: RSRenderExecution::executeAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(325): RSQFCommandException: CCL_RETHROW: RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSLayoutAssembly.cpp(79): RSQFCommandException: CCL_RETHROW: RSLayoutAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(419): RSQFCommandException: CCL_RETHROW: RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchChildrenAssemblyForwardAssembly/RSReportPagesAssembly.cpp(178): RSQFCommandException: CCL_RETHROW: RSReportPagesAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(369): RSQFCommandException: CCL_RETHROW: RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSPageSetAssembly.cpp(467): RSQFCommandException: CCL_RETHROW: RSPageSetAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSAssembly.cpp(686): RSQFCommandException: CCL_RETHROW: RSAssembly::createListIteratorAssembly/RSAssembly.cpp(746): RSQFCommandException: CCL_THROW: RSAssembly::createListIterator.
```

I have searched everywhere for help and I can't seem to find a solution, somebody please help!!

Comment: What data type is `[Yr]`?  If it's an integer or numeric field, try replacing `([Yr])` with `(cast([Yr] as varchar(30)))`.  And yes, Cognos errors are functionally useless.

Comment: Yes BaconBits I have done this, I guess my question should've been how to make this query item the use value for my year prompt? I have to make the yr prompt give me the value 'current period' using stat of 1 from the control table so that we can filter the result of the report based on the most current period. The table has a stat field with 2 distinct values 1 and 0. 1 is for the current yr & mth combination as per the most current load time. I get the right values in the prompts but the error is thrown when I run the report & I know its because of the yr prompt use value. Any suggestions?

Comment: So, wait, the prompts run, but the error happens when the report itself generates?  It almost sounds like you need to make two different prompts, or maybe use a static prompt, and then decode what the two values mean in the report itself.

Comment: Yes the prompts runs where yr prompt gives me all the years plus 'Current Period' & is used as cascade source for the mth prompt & mth prompt gives the most current mth when current period is selected as the year. there is at least 1 other prompt required before the report is generated. I know the prompt works, the error occurs when the report is generated. Static prompts might not be the way as the use value for the year prompt remains the same and that's where the issue comes from, what I am trying to figure out is how to have the yr prompt use a data item that has the case statement in it.